# Is there something for API trading in E-mini S&P 500 Futures or other futures

Tags: programming, algorithmic-trading

I found a lot of results about data feeds, and I found some platforms (like Alpaca) for API trading. But none seem to have the possibility to sell/buy futures via a REST API.

So my question is: Who knows a possibility to sell/buy futures through a REST API?

Regards, Peter

Comment: did you find an API based platform which allow to trade e-mini futures? am looking for the exact same functionality

Comment: Many brokers offer such REST API's (with much wider applicability than just e-minis). For example Client Portal API by IB https://www1.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=5041

Answer (score 2):

Interactive Brokers is probably your best bang for the buck. Using a REST api for trading is fairly amateurish. IB's api works very well for the cost, it's binary, and they've been around a while. any other solution is going to require costs on the order of 10,000 dollars a month just starting out with a firm like Lime brokerage(Wedbush Securities) and the account minimum is $250,000. You cannot do API trading from the internet with Lime, only co-located. I've traded with both but have no interest in either

Answer (score 1):

[QuantRocket](https://www.quantrocket.com/) is a research and trading platform that provides a REST API as well as Python API and CLI and supports trading global futures, equities, and FX through Interactive Brokers. There is [sample code for trading futures](https://www.quantrocket.com/code/?filter=futures) and specific sections of the documentation for [futures](https://www.quantrocket.com/docs/#futures) and [combos](https://www.quantrocket.com/docs/#combos).

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with QuantRocket.